# Check the IniFile descriptor is open

Tags: windows, delphi, file-descriptor

I have a small app, that stores it's settings in INI file. When another form opens, I close INI file descriptor:

```
procedure TIndexForm.startButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  workForm : TForm;
begin

  workForm := TworkingForm.Create(nil);
  workForm.Show();

  configIni.Free; // freeing IniFile desciptor
  IndexForm.Hide();

end;
```

And how I can check the descriptor is still open? Like this(code not working):

```
if not Assigned configIni then
  configIni := TIniFile.Create(configPath);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not just access the INI file as you need it? ie, just create/free long enough to read / write to rather than keeping it open all the time?

Comment: `Assigned` check if a pointer is nil, so when you free the `configIni` variable you must also set the value to nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're welcome to use `Assigned`, but it doesn't check whether a variable refers to a valid object instance. *Nothing does.* Rather, `Assigned` just checks whether a variable is null. To make that a valid check, make your variable null when you free the object it refers to:

```
configIni.Free;
configIni := nil;
```

You can use the `FreeAndNil` helper function if you want; it does little more than what I've written above.